# Calling a SOAP method with PHP with curl functions

Tags: php, curl

i want to try calling soap method in php with curl function but it showing one warning

> Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option in /home/bestbus/public_html/apitest.php on line 26

```
<? 

$xml_data ='<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:rsr="http://webservices.foxfireindia.com/RSRSAPI">
   <soap:Header>
  <rsr:LinkCredentials>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <rsr:Login>***main</rsr:Login>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <rsr:Password>****@3api</rsr:Password>
  </rsr:LinkCredentials>
 </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
  <rsr:Login>
       <!--Optional:-->
       <rsr:userName>***main</rsr:userName>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <rsr:password>****@3api</rsr:password>
  </rsr:Login>
  </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>';

$URL = "http://115.254.89.1:8090/RSRS_APITest/RSRSAPI.asmx?wsdl";

$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($output);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

According the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), the only valid values for CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST are 1 or 2, and the use of 1 has been removed in cURL 7.28.1

- 1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate.
- 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided. In production environments the value of this option should be kept at 2 (default value).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
    $xml_data = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:rsr="http://webservices.foxfireindia.com/RSRSAPI">
   <soap:Header>
  <rsr:LinkCredentials>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <rsr:Login>***main</rsr:Login>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <rsr:Password>****@3api</rsr:Password>
  </rsr:LinkCredentials>
 </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
  <rsr:Login>
       <!--Optional:-->
       <rsr:userName>***main</rsr:userName>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <rsr:password>****@3api</rsr:password>
  </rsr:Login>
  </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>';

    $URL = "http://115.254.89.1:8090/RSRS_APITest/RSRSAPI.asmx?wsdl";
    $header = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    "SOAPAction: \"run\"",
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($tresc),
                    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($output);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
```

with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

because as of documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php CURLOPT_MUTE is removed in cURL 7.15.5